# Migration of older rosdep.yaml bash entries to Groovy

Tags: rosdep, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the preferred method for migrating the old multi-line bash script entries in rosdep.yaml files? REP-0111 says that compatiblity was eliminated in Fuerte:
http://ros.org/reps/rep-0111.html#backwards-compatibility

Multi-line entries in rosdep.yaml used to be interpreted as bash files, allowing fancy manipulations of dependencies. Is there a migration path for these types of entries? If they are no longer permitted, shouldn't the rosdistro default files eliminate any entries that have bash style entries?
https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/base.yaml

I saw that a similar question was asked [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/32786/error-parsing-rosdepyaml-using-rosdep-2-in-ros-fuerte/), but no real solution was given. And placing a sudo requiring make install in a package makefile can get swallowed up in rosmake.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53667/migration-of-older-rosdep.yaml-bash-entries-to-groovy/) by [cmansley](https://answers.ros.org/users/803/cmansley/) on ROS Answers with karma: 198 on 2013-01-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Embedded bash commands are no longer supported by rosdep2.

I don't believe there is any migration path for those rules. So, they should be removed from the rosdistro files.

I would be happy for someone to convince me this answer is wrong.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cmansley](https://answers.ros.org/users/803/cmansley/) on 2013-01-30**:
I understand that they are no longer supported. I am asking what is the migration path? Custom packages have issues with sudo?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-09-17**:
In most cases, the preferred migration path is to create 3rd-party packages instead of downloading and manipulating source code. http://wiki.ros.org/bloom/Tutorials/ReleaseThirdParty  .